# Ansible with_item | first returns no items?

Tags: loops, ansible, undefined

I have an array of JSON like below:

```
[
  {
    "item": {
              "item": "SERVERNAME" 
            } 
  },
  {
    "item": {
              "item": "SERVERNAME2" 
            } 
  }
]
```

On a previous API call I was using

```
     with_items: "{{ cluster_server.results }}"
```

And was able to grab each server name via {{ item.item.item }}

BUT on this API call I only need the first result so using

```
     with_items: "{{ cluster_server.results | first}}"
```

yet it returns this error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'item'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/mycomp/Documents/ansible/build-auth.yml': line 177, column 6, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n   - copy:\n     ^ here\n"}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Fairly new to Ansible.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting `item`, which is your loop variable.  Use another name for the loop variable:

```
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ server.item.item }}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ cluster_server.results | first }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: server
```

Comment: Just as an aside, if you only need the first item, you don't need a loop at all.